# Assign Products created in last 45 days to specific category

Tags: magento-1.7, category, ce-1.7.0.2, category-products

I have a category created in my store with name "New Arrivals"

I want to add all products to this category which are created in last 45 days. This category products should be updated everyday with new products and remove old products.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add more description, do you have a category and assign products to that category?

Comment: I have a category called New arrivals but I need to assign **all recent 45 days new products to that category dynamically**. How is this possible?

Comment: Has it to be a category or can it be a CMS page with a custom product list? So there is no need for cron/observer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code to assign products created in last 45 days to your category.

```
$categoryId = 41; // Your category Id
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$category->setPostedProducts(array()); // Removes all old products added to your category
$category->save(); 
$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$dateStart = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime('-45 days'));
$dateEnd = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', $now);
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from'     => $dateStart,
    'to'       => $dateEnd,
    'datetime' => true
));
$category = array($categoryId);
foreach($collection as $product){
    $category = array_merge($category,$product->getCategoryIds());
    $product->setCategoryIds($category);
    $product->save();
}
```

Create a function with above code in it and use cron to run the same function everyday. It will remove all products from category and update with new products. Refer [How to setup cron](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-configurable-cron/).

Comment: Thanks for the code. The product is assigned to the category in admin panel. But the **product is not showing under that category in frontend**. Why?

Comment: Try reindex and refresh cache. Also make sure your products' visibility is set to "Catalog, Search" and they are in stock.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this, Is it possible to assign this last 45 days new products in Cron job? How to add this in my custom module's Observer.php for Cron job?

Comment: Check updated answer. You can use this code in your observer function as it is.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Can you please let me know how to get & filter the products which price are greater than 50000INR programmatically as like above?

Comment: Hi Jaimin, the above code is not working. Becuase only newly added products are assigning to that specific category, but previously added(last 45 days) products are not assigned to that category. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the products which are not being assigned are created within 45 days from today? Because the code checks for -45 days from now and it should get you products which are created within 45 days.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I just copied the above code. When I add new products, its assigning to that category but if I add new product again, previously added product is removed from that category. So only one product is assigning to that category. **Last 45 days products** are not assigning to that category. This is the output I am getting & am 100% sure.

Comment: I have checked the same code as per your suggestion on my machine and found that it is working. Can you check your database table `catalog_product_entity` for product created date format.

Comment: Try with updated code. You can also update date format as per your format.

Comment: Updated code is working. But I am facing the issue with it.  I have already 3 products(created within 45 days) in that category. If I add some more products(e.g 4 products) means, that 4 products assigned to that category successfully. But previously added 3 products were deleted. Here actually seven(3+4) products have to be added. I have also checked and confirmed in `catalog_product_entity` table as per your suggestion. In that table 7 products are listed within 45 days time.

Comment: This is working for me :

Comment: How? Did you make any change to the code as it was not working before.

Comment: I have changed few things and now its working fine

Comment: Great, please post your code as answer to the question. It will help others who are looking for it.

Comment: `$categoryId = 15;$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);$category->setPostedProducts(array());$category->save();$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$dateStart = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', strtotime('-45 days'));
$dateEnd = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', $now);
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from' => $dateStart,'to'  => $dateEnd,'datetime' => true
));foreach($collection as $product){ $product->setCategoryIds('15'); $product->save();} `

Comment: But the full credits goes to you @Jaimin. Thanks.

Comment: Please update this answer.

Comment: Updated the answer as per suggestion, thanks @mesk

Comment: Hi Jaimin, this code is working like a charm. But I have one minor issue. All the recent 45 products are assigned to this(New Arrivals) category. But while adding the products I also assigned another categories as well. So this products assigned to only **New Arrivals** category. But I need to assign another category as well while creating the products. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: @mesk, Please check with updated code.

Comment: Hi Jaimin, I have updated Magento version from 1.7 to 1.9. After that its not working. why?