# Dynamically display the products which price is greater than some amount in specific category

Tags: magento-1.7, category, ce-1.7.0.2, category-products

I have a category **Costly Products**. I have some products which price are costly(e.g 50000INR). So, in that category, I need to **display/list the products which are greater than 50000INR dynamically**.

**Note :** I don't want to assign the costly products to that category. If I add the products(greater than 50000INR), it will automatically listed in that category.

What's the possibility to get this? Any ideas welcomed with thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign Products created in last 45 days to specific category](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165776/assign-products-created-in-last-45-days-to-specific-category)

Comment: Please do not post your questions twice

Answer (score 0):

Write a cron job which will run frequently (ex: hourly,daily etc). In that job

Get the all products and find the products with price more then '50000'.

Then check whether those products are present in 'costly category', if not then programmatically add those to category.

Comment: I am new to Magento. Can you please let me know how to do this?